# What does σ mean, in context of gtg response time in monitors?

Tags: display

I was looking forward to buying an Asus monitor and in their [specification sheet](https://www.asus.com/us/Monitors/VZ229H/specifications/), it was mentioned that the response time is `5ms (GTGσ)`. A cursory search did not yield any good results except for [this thread](http://www.overclock.net/t/1364656/in-response-time-5ms-gtg-what-mean) which claims that `5ms (GTGσ)` is essentially `14ms (GTG)` which is a deal-breaker for me. But, I cannot find any further sources to support this claim.

So, what exactly does the `σ` signify in context of response time and is the claim of `5ms (GTGσ) == 14ms (GTG)` true?

Comment: If there are any sources, they are indeed hard to find. `GTGσ` is similar to a [*sepulka*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sepulka). This makes me believe it was invented just to describe response times with lower numbers to lure clients. Note there is no industry standard for sole `GTG` as well.